# How to add jQuery Mobile to HTML

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I can't get this to work (from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-collapsible.html):

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
   <h3>I'm a header</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
</div>
```

I'm assuming it's because I haven't included jQuery mobile or something, but I'm not sure what I should add. This is what I have in my HTML head right now:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/main_script.js"></script>
```

So basically, jquery and external javascript. How do I add jquery mobile? Or is that even the problem?

Comment: add jquery mobile like you have added the jquery.js script.. and make sure it is after the jquery.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are not including the jQuery mobile plugin.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x7TQ2/)

Comment: Thought so. That seems to have fixed it, thanks. :D

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the Mobile-JQuery library without which data-role="collapsible" will not work

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/Yg7bu/)